# CSS Sibling's Children Selector

Tags: css, parent-child, parent, siblings

I have the following structure that I've simplified down, the goal here was to set the span with the class "*partA*" background color to pink **because** the input has the class "*state*".

The internal structure of the "*container*" cannot change.

So the end result for this example would be the first "Content" label would be highlighted pink.

Note that there can be any number of "*container*"s in any order throughout the page structure, so just selecting the first container isn't a suitable solution.

```
<span class="container">
    <span class="item">
        <span class="partA">Content</span>
        <span class="partB">A</span>
    </span>
    <input class="element state" />
</span>

<span class="container">
    <span class="item">
        <span class="partA">Content</span>
        <span class="partB">B</span>
    </span>
    <input class="element" />
</span>
```

I thought the general sibling selector may be the solution, but it doesn't seem to work - I believe because it's a sibling of the parent, not the element itself.  I tried both ways round in case I had made a mistake:

```
.partA ~ .state { background-color: pink; }
.state ~ .partA { background-color: pink; }
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvwh5uw0/) with this structure.

Can anyone provide me a selector which will accomplish this?  I would like to avoid JS if at all possible.

Comment: You can never navigate up with css selectors... Then, no cousins or uncles may be targeted

Comment: I was hoping there was someway to select the children of an element with a sibling, so as to not navigate up in that sense...

Comment: In the future, if a parent or ancestor selector comes about then yes, but for now you'd need JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

CSS renders always in a forward sequence. So, what you want could only work if the `input` came first in the structure:

```css
.state ~ span .partA { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<span class="container">
    <input class="element state" />
    <span class="item">
        <span class="partA">Content</span>
        <span class="partB">A</span>
    </span>
</span>

<span class="container">
    <input class="element" />
    <span class="item">
        <span class="partA">Content</span>
        <span class="partB">B</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the HTML structure of the container has to work as is as it's generated by a third party library.  It would otherwise have been a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)

> "there are no parent selectors in CSS, not even in CSS3"

The article is worth a read, but I suspect the only way you are going to be able to do this is with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer a sort-of-solution that might work for you.

**HTML**

```
<span class="container">
<input class="element state" />
<span class="item">
    <span class="partA">Content</span>
    <span class="partB">A</span>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.state ~ .item .partA { background-color: pink; }
```

This way you swap the DOM elements around, which you than could position with CSS.
See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/edkyy360/4/

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the HTML structure of the container has to work as is as it's generated by a third party library. It would otherwise have been a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not possible to back-track selectors using pure CSS
let's find a solution adding the minimal effort:

Place this before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
// Add PINK background to the first `.partA` element whose uncle has `.state`
var stateClass = document.getElementsByClassName("state");
for(var i=0; i<stateClass.length; i++){
  stateClass[i].parentElement.getElementsByClassName("partA")[0].style.background = "pink";
}
</script>
```

```js
var stateClass = document.getElementsByClassName("state");

for(var i=0; i<stateClass.length; i++){
  stateClass[i].parentElement.getElementsByClassName("partA")[0].style.background = "pink"
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="item">
    <span class="partA">Content</span>
    <span class="partB">A</span>
  </span>
  <input class="element state" />
</span>

<span class="container">
  <span class="item">
    <span class="partA">Content</span>
    <span class="partB">B</span>
  </span>
  <input class="element" />
</span>
```